# How to get the max value of an int[] in J2ME?

Tags: java, java-me

There is an int[] variable , for example `private int[3] tInt = new int[]{6,9,4};`

In this example `9` is the max value.

So how to write a **J2ME** code to get the max value of an Int[] ?

Comment: This is one of the first algorithms to be learned when people start to study CS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE; // or max = tInt[0]
for (int i = 0; i < tInt.length; i ++) {
    if (tInt[i] > max) {
       max = tInt[i];
    }
}

System.out.println("Max is: " + max);
```

You can see some 3rd party libraries. It's unlikely that you will will use them in JavaME, but just for the sake of completeness (they use the same code as above)

- guava: `Ints.max(tInt)`
- commons-lang: `NumberUtils.max(tInt)`

Answer (score 0):

```
max = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) 
            {
                if(max < array[i])
                {
                   max = array[i]; 
                }
            }
```

Comment: Assumes that the max value will be positive. Would need `max = Integer.MIN_VALUE`